# how to deal with the comma in String args[] in java

Tags: java

My code is working perfectly without passing any comma in the command. I am not sure how to change my code to deal with the comma in the command.

This is what I have now :

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String key = args[0]; // key
    int n = (int) Math.sqrt(args.length - 1);
    
        String mat[][] = new String[n][n]; //matrix 

        int count = 1;
        for (int r = 0; r < n; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < n; c++){
                if (count == args.length)
                    break;
                mat[r][c] = args[count];
                count++;
            }

        }
    find_key(mat,n,key);

    
}
```

When I run

java findKey 15 60 10 9 20 8 4 12 7 3

My output: Not found

java findKey 3 60 10 9 20 8 4 12 7 3

My output: Location: (3,3)

However, The program must accept several command line arguments.  The first argument is the key being sought, and successive arguments are the elements of the square matrix, row-column, where each row is delimited by a comma, and infinity is abbreviated with an I.
Two sample invocations, and their corresponding matrices, are

```
Invocaiton 1:java findKey 15 60 10 9, 20 8 4, 12 7 3 
Invocaiton 2:java findKey 71 I I 71 20, I I 60 17, 72 41 12 5, 27 5 4 3
```

For the first invocation, the key = 15 and the 3×3 matrix does NOT contain that key, hence the output should be not found.  In the second invocation,key=71 in the 4×4 matrix, and it does contain the key, so the output should be(1,3)).

Comment: Do you want to just ignore the comma or do you need to use it to check the input?

Comment: I probably just want to ignore the comma @Matt

Comment: Why do you want to insert a comma into the command in the first place? Maybe something like [Commons CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/) library (from Apache) is appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comment, you want to ignore the comma. In this case, you can just remove it from the arguments when assigning the value to an element of `mat`.

```
mat[r][c] = args[count].replace(",", "")
```

---

Some background information: The string represented by `args[]` gets split by spaces so the resulting elements of the array look like this:

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| 15| 60| 10| 9,| 20|  8| 4,| 12|  7|  3|
```

Therefore, the comma is part of the last element of the row and can simply be removed.